# Convert pandas Timestamp to string

Tags: python-3.x

```
    import datetime
    from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    print(today-BDay(3))
```

I got
`Timestamp('2021-05-19 19:31:36.049610')`
how do I convert above to string
`'2021-05-19'`
?

As a side question: What is the exact package the contains the `Timestamp`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try `(today-BDay(3)).to_pydatetime().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`
2. from `pandas.Timestamp`